# In python While writing If conditions by using False boolean condition,I am getting nothing as output, showing that indented code gets skipped, why?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

inbox_full = False
if inbox_full:
print("Your inbox is full")

By performing the above condition in python I am getting the code skipped ..why this is happening so.

Comment: Could you please clarify? When executing your line of code I get a syntax error in `python3` and nothing is exeucted (even if inbox_full is defined beforehands). If you replaced the `:` with an `else` that'ld be different. Which python interpreter are you using and what exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

The indented code gets executed only when the condition provided in the if statement is true, otherwise it is skipped.

In your code the condition for the if statement is set to False that's why it is getting skipped.